# Constant member

Tags: c++, static, constants, structure

I have structure defined in some header (D3DXVECTOR3)

How can I declare:

1. static member in the class of that type and initialize it?
2. maybe constant member of that type and init it?

*when i use some constructor i get error only integral can be initialized.*

Comment: Can we see your non working code please?

Comment: static const D3DXVECTOR3 g = D3DXVECTOR3(1,1); //only integral static const can be initialized
i tried also pointers

Comment: Please show us your complete work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in header file I declared

```
class Bar_class
{
  static const D3DXVECTOR3 foo;
}
```

in cpp file I wrote

```
const D3DXVECTOR3 Bar_class::foo =D3DXVECTOR3 (1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [initializer list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) to initialize const members.

For example

```
struct demo
{

    const int x;

    demo():x(10)
    {
        //some code
    }

};
```

As far as initializing static members(inside the class) is concerned (you can initialize them inside the class only if they are `const-static` integers)

```
For example

struct abc{

     static const int k=10; //fine
     static int p=10; //Invalid
     static const double r =2.3 //Invalid
      // ......

   };

  const int abc::k ; //Definition
```

Comment: as i understood I have to write some wrapper around that struct?
it is rather complex because of structure complexity
and how to initialize them if they are const static thnx.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just modify the already-existing struct. That would be a redefinition. Not fun stuff.

You can wrap it like TGadfly suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To have a static member of non-`int` type, use the following construct:

```
class foo {
    // Declarations:
    static Type1 field1; // or
    static Type2 const field1;
};

// Definitions and initializations:
Type1 foo::field1 = value1;
Type2 const foo::field2 = value2;
```